# How to properly redefine/restart Jet's job after fault?

Tags: java, hazelcast-jet

The Jet's [manual](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/latest/manual/#job) says that one job could be submitted multiple times. But, when I try to restart it after some exception I'll get the exception like "Cannot restart failed job". If I'll do nothing I get no exceptions but computation is not performed inside pipeline.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an erratum in the manual of Jet 0.6.1:

> The same `Job` instance can be submitted for execution many times.

What you actually submit for execution is a `Pipeline` or a `Dag`, and a `Job` is your handle to one specific execution. So you can get many `Job` instances for the same `Pipeline` or `Dag`. `Job.restart()` doesn't mean "restart from scratch", but "stop and start" the same job, continuing where it left.

Once a job fails, you're free to submit another job with the same `Pipeline` instance, but there's no mechanism to automatically retry from scratch after any failure.

Answer (score 1):

The restart method is only valid for running jobs. Once a job is failed, currently there's no way to start it again. What you'll need to do on a failure would be to submit the same job again as a new job. For streaming jobs, you might want to handle any intermittent exceptions so that they do not cause the job to fail.